# Camel catching jdbc exception ClassNotFound running on karaf

Tags: java, maven, exception, jdbc, apache-camel

I'm trying to catch the the exception in my camel route that is thrown when jdbc can't get the connection which is

```
org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException
```

To do this I got the following camel blueprint route

```
[...]
<doTry>
    <to uri="sql:UPDATE log SET field = :#value" />
    <doCatch>
        <exception>org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException</exception>
        <process ref="exceptionProcessor"></process>
    </doCatch>
</doTry>
[...]
```

But now I get

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException
```

I already tried to add the dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

in my pom.xml or to import the package in the maven-bundle-plugin

```
<Import-Package>org.springframework.jdbc.*;*</Import-Package>
```

which both didn't work.

I only can catch 'java.lang.Exception' now. How can I do this with the

```
org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException
```

Exception?

Answer (score -1):

You are missing to connector?

Download it here for mysql 
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

Even though you imported jbdc from maven you still need to include the connector in maven the mysql connector is, (no need to download the link above if you use maven like below)

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.9</version>
    </dependency>
```

If you aren't using mysql there are other dependencies you need for connecting to different types of databases.

Comment: Still getting ClassNotFound for the 'org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException' :/

Comment: You may have deployed your program many times and now there's too many connections.

Comment: My problem is not about getting a connection to the MySQL - that works fine. It is about handling the exception when it is not reachable for whatever reason because everything also has to work in this case. So the problem is not about too many connections or something like this. It is just that camel can't find the Exception class to handle it.